# SQL Server 2008 R2 database detaches when windows server restarts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008

I have a weird problem, I have a database and it was working just fine until now, every time I restart my server, the database seem to disappear. After extensive research I found out that the database just detaches, so I have to attach it again after the server restarts. I can't find a solution to this, has anyone come across it?

- I did many virus scans, but nothing, so It can't be a virus.
- I have also tried repairing the sql and that didn't work.
- I have tried to take this database and added to my test environment, and it seem to work fine.

It is not the database itself, I'm guessing something in SQL Server that is corrupt or a virus? I have SQL Server 2008 R2 on a **Windows Server 2008**

Comment: Possibly post on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ ?